# Query in python for elasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am new in elasticSearch i just want to know if there's a fastest way to do this query:

```
res = es.search(size=10000,
                scroll='1m',
                index='myindex',
                body={"query": {
                       "bool": {
                           "must": [
                               {"term": {"Plant": 6204}},
                               {"range": {
                                    "Date shift end": {
                                        "gte": "2016-07-01",
                                        "lte": "2016-08-31"}}}]}}})
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `scroll` to retrieve documents, you may set the `size` parameter to a smaller one. Then, you can use the `scroll_id` that is return last time to get the next `size` number of documents, by call another API methods:

```
scroll_res = es.scroll(scroll_id=scroll_id, scroll='2m') #Set another scroll expiry time
```